# Magento 2: Get order via API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I need to get out of order information via api, but i didn't know what to do, anyone help me, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `/V1/orders/{id}` endpoint in order to get information

```
   $userData = array("username" => "abc", "password" => "abc123");
   $ch = curl_init("https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

   $token = curl_exec($ch);

   $requesturl = "https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/".$Yourorderid;


    $ch = curl_init($requesturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $orderdata = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($orderdata); echo "</pre>";
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: this is result https://prnt.sc/pb4382 please check it.

Comment: @MichaelHa you have to use your website admin username and password in order to fetch token